# Not able to start supervisor with Django

Tags: django, celery, supervisord

I have a Django application and I use Celery to run background task.
I am using supervisor to run celery as a service, but when I run: `sudo supervisorctl reread` , it gives me following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 578, in _build_master
ws.require(__requires__)
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 895, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
 pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (supervisor 4.0.0.dev0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages), 
  Requirement.parse('supervisor==3.3.1'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/supervisorctl", line 6, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3112, in <module>
@_call_aside
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3096, in _call_aside
f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3125, in _initialize_master_working_set
working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 580, in _build_master
return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
 File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 593, in _build_from_requirements
dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 781, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'supervisor==3.3.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Update with supervisiord config file:-

**supervisord.conf :**

```
; supervisor config file

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
 chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

 [supervisord]
 logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log 
  file;default 
   $CWD/supervisord.log)
  pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default 
 supervisord.pid)
 childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = 
supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a 
unix socket

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

Celery config files:

**celery_proj_worker.conf**

```
; ==================================
; celery worker supervisor example
; ==================================
; the name of your supervisord program
 [program:proj_worker]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
 command=/home/me/proj/venv/bin/celery -A proj worker -l info
 ; The directory to your Django project
directory=/home/me/proj
; If supervisord is run as the root user, switch users to this UNIX 
 user account before doing any processing.
user=me
; Supervisor will start as many instances of this program as named by 
numprocs
numprocs=1
; Put process stdout output in this file 
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/proj_worker.log
; Put process stderr output in this file 
 stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/proj_worker.log
 ; If true, this program will start automatically when supervisord is 
 started
  autostart=true
 ; May be one of false, unexpected, or true. If false, the process will never be autorestarted. If unexpected, the process will be restart when the program exits with an exit code that is not one of the exit codes associated with this process’ configuration (see exitcodes). If true, the process will be unconditionally restarted when it exits, without regard to its exit code.
  autorestart=true
  ; The total number of seconds which the program needs to stay running after a startup to consider the start successful.
 startsecs=10
 ; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown. ; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
 stopwaitsecs = 600 
 ; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it ; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead, taking care of its children as well.
 killasgroup=true
 ; if your broker is supervised, set its priority higher so it starts first
priority=998
```

**celery_proj_beat.conf**

```
; ================================
;  celery beat supervisor example
; ================================ 
; the name of your supervisord program
[program:projbeat]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
 command=/home/me/proj/venv/bin/celery -A proj beat -l info
; The directory to your Django project
directory=/home/me/proj
; If supervisord is run as the root user, switch users to this UNIX 
user account before doing any processing.
user=me
; Supervisor will start as many instances of this program as named by numprocs
numprocs=1
; Put process stdout output in this file 
 stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/proj_beat.log
; Put process stderr output in this file 
 stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/proj_beat.log
; If true, this program will start automatically when supervisord is started
autostart=true
 ; May be one of false, unexpected, or true. If false, the process will never be autorestarted. If unexpected, the process will be restart when the program exits with an exit code that is not one of the exit codes associated with this process’ configuration (see exitcodes). If true, the process will be unconditionally restarted when it exits, without regard to its exit code.
autorestart=true
; The total number of seconds which the program needs to stay running after a startup to consider the start successful.
startsecs=10
; if your broker is supervised, set its priority higher so it starts first
priority=999
```

Any suggestions are welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post your supervisor config file?

Comment: @CoolestNerdIII Please check, I have updated my question with supervisord.conf file.

Comment: Can you show the file with your celery config?

Comment: @CoolestNerdIII Please check the updated question.

Comment: 1. In your celery beat file, I believe your directory is different than all the other directories

Comment: @CoolestNerdIII My project file is somewhere in /home/me/proj, and celery log files are under /var/log/celery. The supervisor conf files are- /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf, and supervisord.conf is under- /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf.

Comment: You have /home/me/sites/proj vs /home/me/prob

Comment: @CoolestNerdIII I have corrected this, but still error persist. Is there a problem with Python version? I am using Python 3.6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183164/discussion-between-coolestnerdiii-and-reema-parakh).

Answer (score -1):

Based on supervisor [documents](https://pypi.org/project/supervisor/), it will not work under any version of Python 3.

Comment: I see you are short of reps, but this is really just a comment. This type of  answer attracts downvotes or gets flagged
___I did not DV___ and if that happens you will loose rep points and take longer to get to the 50 reps you need to comment on any question.
Until then, stick to questions that are well asked and therefore easily answered without
needing clarification. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead